# Open file upload dialog in Safari

Tags: javascript

I'm using Javascript to open a native file dialog. This works on all browser's except Safari. The action is triggered by the user (via the `onClick` attribute on an anchor tag), but there is some indirection that might cause the issue. My usecase is uploading (small) images to a local DB (using [localForage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage)).

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
function uploadImage(id) {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'file';
  input.onchange = e => {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = readerEvent => {
      var content = readerEvent.target.result;
      // do something with the file content here
      }
    }
  }
  // check if we already have an image for that id
  localforage.getItem(id).then(function(value) {
    if (!value) {
      input.click();
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
  })
}
```

I understand that there are some security restrictions preventing from triggering the click event programmatically. Is Safari implementing those in a stricter way, or why does this work in other browsers?

How can I modify my code to work on Safari?

Comment: I'd use a label instead of an anchor. Labels that are properly associated with a file input field, already trigger the file selection dialog, without any additional JavaScript.

Comment: @CBroe they do need the JS to determine if they need to show the file picker or not.

Comment: @Kaiido I can't really tell what's needed, from this minimal code snippet. The explanation even talks about an _"onClick attribute on an anchor tag"_, which I don't see anything of here anywhere.

Comment: @CBroe You can see that the call to `.click()` is made inside an `if (!value)` clause, itself in a pretty well commented call block.

Comment: @Kaiido that's an input element getting clicked there though, and not the "anchor element with onclick attribute" they were talking about.

Comment: @CBroe that doesn't change the fact that they do need JS anyway in their current setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are waiting for the asynchronous IDB response before triggering again the click event. The one you're handling is thus probably already deemed dead by the time you call `click()`. (Though IIRC it's supposed to be something like 1 full second in Safari, which seems pretty long for an IDB response...).

As a workaround, you could try to check for the existence of the file in an earlier event e.g. `mouseenter`, which might create useless requests, or `mousedown`, but that may still not be enough, and even if it does work on your system you can't be sure it will everywhere...

So the best in your case is probably to check way earlier for every possible id you set in the document if it's already available or not, store that information and do everything synchronously in the event handler.

Comment: Keeping a set of ids and keeping everything in the event handler synchronously works. Thank you! Code becomes if setOfIds.has(id) { ... } else { input.click(); }